# Can I use Amazon Comprehend in a React app?

Tags: javascript, python, reactjs

I want to use Amazon Comprehend to analyze news articles so that I can display the key phrases, entities, and sentiment for each article. I'm reading all the documentation and it's all for Python: can I use Amazon Comprehend in a React app using JavaScript?

If it is possible, how do I bring it in to the app? I cannot find examples of what to install/import.

Comment: Sounds like you're probably reading documentation for the Python SDK. AWS has SDKs in several languages, including JavaScript: https://aws.amazon.com/tools/

Comment: Thank you! I don't know how I didn't find that before, it helped a lot. I'm able to call the function I need in my app now, I just need to fine-tune what I send.